# Reference two foreign keys in Django data model

Tags: python, django

I want to reference two foreign keys in the Conversation model, because user_one and user_two can be a Person or Business either way. What is the best way of expressing this?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """
    Person model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar_path, blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Business(models.Model):
    """
    Business model
`   """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)


class Conversation(models.Model):
    """
    Conversation model
    Contains conversation relational data between registered users
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    #user_one = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, default=None)
    #user_two = models.ForeignKey(Business, null=True, default=None)


class ConversationReply(models.Model):
    """
    Conversation reply model
    Contains conversation reply data
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, null=True, default=None)
    reply = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: You might want to look into [`generic foreign keys`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [django model inheratance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/) and create an Entity model.

```
 class Entity(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
         abstract = True

 class Person(Entity):
    """
    Person model
    """

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar_path, blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Business(Entity):
    """
    Business model
`   """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)


class Conversation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    content_object_1 = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_1_id')
    content_object_2 = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_2_id')
```

Note that due to the use of `GenericForeignKey` filtering will not work the traditional way. Then you'll be able to do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

contenttype_obj = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(person_object)

Conversation.objects.filter(object_id_1=person_object.id, content_type=contenttype_obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting the following error message now: `Field defines a relation with model 'Entity', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`

Comment: This happens at `entity_1` and `entity_2`

Comment: To solve this you can use `GenericForeignKey` as ozgur stated. I've edited my answer accordingly.